# If the Doctor were to open the TARDIS under water in the ocean, what would happen?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

I've always wondered what would happen, and have asked my friends a few times, but without a satisfying response.

Comment: Kind of a speculative open-ended question, because it depends on the writer and the era.  You could have the tardis filling up, or you could have an invisible barrier keep the water out.  Depending on how the particular writer/crew wanted to take it.

Comment: @MarkRogers Without the barrier, woulde the tardis fill up, or would the oceans disappear into the depths of the tardis?

Comment: @user14111: Whatever Moffat needs ;)

Comment: Man, ocean doesn’t have enough water to fill the TARDIS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it true that The Doctor can only regenerate 12 times?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/809/is-it-true-that-the-doctor-can-only-regenerate-12-times)

Comment: I imagine the oceans would drain away to nothing... the interior of the TARDIS is likely much larger in volume than the Pacific. Then again, you can open the door in outer space if you want to take a peek... it's probably user-friendly enough to toss up a forcefield before anything catastrophic occurs.

Comment: Presumably either A: the Tardis floods or B: the atmospheric shell acts as a barrier like it did in the beginning of The Beast Below

Comment: @John The dead TARDISs we saw in The Doctor's Wife certainly weren't bigger than the Pacific. Why do you think this one is?

Comment: We've seen the TARDIS hold its atmosphere at the door many, many times. No reason to think that holding back water is any different to "holding back" vacuum in a scenario such as this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - easy... those were dead. Without the time vortex or the matrix, it's just a ship. The "corpse" of a TARDIS is whatever physical form it assumed before dying. In the case of Doctor Who's TARDIS, that's a blue police box with a fixed interior, even though the fixed interior is still larger than the exterior would seem to allow.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We actually see this in "[Listen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Listen_(Doctor_Who))", where the TARDIS is opened underwater. With all of its systems working correctly, it simply remains trapped inside its own air bubble with the water held at a safe distance outside.

[image]

As to how this is achieved; in the episode "[Logopolis](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/18-7.htm)" there is a [lengthy discussion](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1b9ej5_115-logopolis-2-of-4_tv&start=421) of the doctor's plan to open the TARDIS doors underwater. From this conversation we can deduce two main facts;

### A substantial number of systems need to be shut down in order to allow water to enter through the doors

### ∴ Under normal circumstances, the doors can be opened without suffering a catastrophic influx of water

> **DOCTOR:** *No, how can we with the Master in the Tardis? They're a retiring people. They like a quiet life. There's no telling what a
> creature like that would do on Logopolis.*
> **ADRIC:** *So how do we flush him out?*
> **DOCTOR:** *And there's no saying what that might do to the Tardis systems. Can you swim?*
> **ADRIC:** *Yes.*
> **DOCTOR:** *Good. Materialise the Tardis underwater and open the door.*
> (Down in the Cloister Room, Tegan walks round the police box. The door
> opens invitingly.  The Doctor calls up an aerial view of London on the
> scanner.)
>
> **DOCTOR:** *That's the River Thames. We'll put down there.*
> **ADRIC:** ***And water sluices in and floods out the whole Tardis.***
> **DOCTOR:** *Yes. Adric, shut down everything. Fold back the Omega configuration.*   (Adric gets on the floor underneath the console.)
> **ADRIC:** *Folded back.*
> **DOCTOR:** *Good. Exponential cross-field?*
> **ADRIC:** *Halted.*
> **DOCTOR:** *Good. Pathways to conditional states seven to seventeen?*
> **ADRIC:** *Closed.*
> **DOCTOR:** *Excellent. Main and auxiliary drive?*
> **ADRIC:** *Ended.*
> **DOCTOR:** *Good. Now, we're partially materialised, so there'll be a slight jolt. Are you ready?*
> **ADRIC:** *If you are.*
> **DOCTOR:** *What? Well, I'd feel more confident if you just said yes.*
> **ADRIC:** *Yes.*
> **DOCTOR:** *Good. Here we go, then.*
>
> [Cloister room]
> (Tegan gets jolted.)
>
> **TEGAN:** *This is too much!*
>
> [Tardis]
> **DOCTOR:** *A gentle splash-down.*
> (Thud! They fall to the floor.)
> **DOCTOR:** *We must have touched bottom.*
> **ADRIC:** *Touched bottom?*
> **DOCTOR:** *Yes. Good thing the water was there to break our fall.*
>
> [Cloister room]
> **TEGAN:** *Crazy idiot of a pilot! Wait till I have a word with him.*
> (Laughter comes from the open door of the police box.)
> **TEGAN:** *Who's that?*
>
> [Tardis]
> (The Doctor is standing braced across the doors.)
> **DOCTOR:** *Careful, now. The water pressure could send us both flying. Ready?*
> **ADRIC:** *Yes.*
> **DOCTOR:** *Now!*
> (Adric presses a button and runs to join the Doctor. The doors do not move.)
>
> **DOCTOR:** *That's odd. There's no pressure on those doors at all.*
> **ADRIC:** *Perhaps we aren't down very deep.  (The doors swing open and they step outside* [onto dry land])

Answer (score 29):

Since it's never happened on screen, any answer would be pure speculation. However, since we've frequently seen the Doctor open the Tardis door in deep space - in both classic and modern series - without the air rushing out, we can speculate that the same force would stop the water rushing in.

Comment: I remember an episode where River jumps from a building and the TARDIS catches her - she falls into the swimming pool. There is a large splash of water coming out of the TARDIS' doors, and then, the water comes back inside. Not sure if that proves anything, but that may suggest that there is no real water barrier around the TARDIS. But then again, the Doctor could've turned it off for the moment. But then again, all I have is speculation.

Comment: It has happened on screen. See above.

Answer (score 5):

In the episode *The Beast Below*, the Doctor references an "[air shell](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Air_corridor)". This allows a sustainable environment for the TARDIS and the residing occupants to have the ability to open the doors and be on the immediate outside.

The reason we often see the TARDIS constantly filled with water, I presume, is that the air field must be enlarged manually, otherwise it is automatically at a minimum. Or it just looks cooler.

Comment: “The reason we often see the TARDIS constantly filled with water” – we do? When?

Answer (score 5):

In Logopolis the fourth Doctor tried to land the TARDIS underwater in order to flood the TARDIS. Unfortunately we never saw what happened as the TARDIS materialised on a barge instead of dropping to the bottom of the Thames.

Answer (score 4):

We see this at the start of Series 8, Episode 4 "Listen" where The Doctor does open the TARDIS doors underwater.

Nothing happens. The TARDIS maintains a shell around it which doesn't let any water in.

Answer (score 1):

TECHNICALLY, in the episode with Donna Noble, when she opened the TARDIS when David Tennant was Doctor, she asked why they were breathing. The doctor replied with the fact that there was an oxygen field surrounding the TARDIS, which would also mean that no water would be able to get inside when the shields are up.

Answer (score 0):

Disney mermaid in the second left picture has the tardis also opening underwater

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What is the source of this image?  Is it just fan art?