# Can the Doctor give himself unlimited regenerations?

Tags: doctor-who, regeneration

Keeping within the official *Doctor Who* canon, is it possible that the Doctor could transfer regeneration energy to his past self an unlimited number of times? Is there any aspect of the Whoniverse that would indicate that this is not possible?

Comment: Possibly already answered here? : http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/809/is-it-true-that-the-doctor-can-only-regenerate-12-times

Comment: It seems there is no twelve cycle limit, but can he transfer regenerations to his past self? This may remain unanswered until the methods of transferring a regeneration are clearly revealed.

Comment: to be clear. There *is* a twelve-regeneration limit unless the Council of Time Lords intervenes somehow; so The Doctor cannot give *himself* more regenerations.

Comment: It’s possible, but only if the ratings are high enough.

Comment: If this was possible the Valeyard wouldn't have had to stage a trial to get the Doctor's regenerations. When he was feeling a bit low he could just pop somewhere he knew the Doctor would be and siphon off some regeneration energy.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield what special power does the Council of Time Lords have that cannot be circumvented in some manner?

Comment: In the War Games, the second Doctor states that, barring accidents, Time Lords can live forever.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not certain that transferring regenerations between himself at different points in his timeline would work as supported by *Who* canon. Of course, if a writer felt such a solution was the answer to a problem, everything would be Timey-Wimey and such a feat would be accomplished regardless, but I can't point to any extant material that supports such a scheme.

That said, it *is* possible to gain more regenerations. The Doctor received a new cycle of regenerations from the Time Lords in *The Time of the Doctor* after all! Similarly, the High Council of Gallifrey offered a new cycle of regenerations to the Master in *The Five Doctors,* and the Master claimed in *The Sound of the Drums* that the Time Lords resurrected him to fight in the Time War, granting him a new cycle of regenerations in the process.

The exact system for granting a new cycle remains unexplained.

Comment: Good point. The only time we've actually seen regeneration energy transferred from one Time Lord to another was for healing purposes which never resulted in the recipient gaining a regeneration.

Answer (score 3):

I feel certain the answer is no - The Doctor could not use time travel to keep giving himself his regeneration energy back - for TWO reasons - one canon, the other is simple mathematics.

In-universe, The Doctor meeting him/herself is in itself an *anomaly*. When Doctors from other timelines leave, they do not return to their timeline - they do not "retain" the experience. Whatever happens during this anomaly does not return with them to their timeline, and only the remaining Doctor whose timeline it was retains the experience. Note this conversation from *The Day of The Doctor*:

> WAR DOCTOR: I won't remember this, will I?
> ELEVEN: The time streams are out of sync. You can't retain it, no.

But even if all that could be ignored, the mathematics of it means it isn't possible.

Ignoring this new part of The Doctor's previous existence as 'The Timeless Child' that we currently know nothing about (or even if it is all true), we must assume that, even if The Doctor did previously have unlimited regeneration power, The Time Lords found a way to limit The Doctor to 12 regenerations (making for 13 lives), perhaps using the same genetic engineering they used on everybody else. If this were not the case then Eleven would not have sat dying of old age, unable to regenerate until a new cycle was bestowed upon him. If The Doctor holds enough energy for 12 regenerations, he could only give his past self *whatever was left*, so he could still only have 12 regenerations. Also, if a Time Lord can only *hold* 12 regenerations, it isn't possible to "stock up" on regenerations.

Example:

> Sixth Doctor has 7 regenerations left. He travels **back** in time to meet First Doctor. First Doctor is already holding 12, so he can't hold any more.
>
> Sixth Doctor travels **forward** in time to give Eleven (who is actually Thirteen because of Ten's wasted regeneration and The War Doctor) his remaining 7 regenerations. This causes an anomaly, because no matter how many regenerations he gives Eleven, Six now does not have enough regenerations to ever *become* Eleven.
>
> Ten travels **back** to give Nine his remaining regeneration. Nine now has one extra regeneration, but for this to be sustainable, he must do the same when he becomes Ten, so he won't actually get an extra regeneration at all. After he gives the extra back to himself as Ten, he will just have his original 1 (or 2, depending on whether Ten has wasted his regeneration on his hand yet) left.

Answer (score 2):

No, he has a limit. This was addressed in The Deadly Assassin, The Doctor Who movie, and confirmed in The Time of the Doctor. If you rewatch some of the episodes, you'll see that the War Doctor does count as a regeneration (and is actually the true 9th incarnation), then he regenerated into the 9th Doctor (10th incarnation), then he changed into the 10th Doctor (11th incarnation), then he regenerated and almost changed in The Stolen Earth/Journey's End (making him the 12th incarnation, possibly, but with the same face), and then he changed into the 11th Doctor (13th incarnation). In the special, the Doctor mentions that every single regeneration counts, including his Warrior one, and the fact that his 10th/11th incarnation regenerated twice, makes it so that the 11th Doctor was always going to be the face he dies as (hence The Fall of The Eleventh). The Time Lords ended up giving him a new regeneration cycle, proving that he couldn't just give himself regenerations, because if he could, the 10th Doctor might have avoided changing for god knows how long. Even with the new cycle, we're not sure how many regenerations he has now, but he clearly has a limit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes If The Master is to be believed. In The Season 12 finale of *Doctor Who*, “The Timeless Children“, The Master persuades the Doctor to join him on Gallifrey, where he forces her to enter the Matrix. He shows her the secret history of Gallifrey and its native Shobogans.

Tecteun, a space explorer, found a "timeless child" with infinite capacity to regenerate.

She adopted the child and studied her, successfully grafting her regeneration capacity into the Shobogans, transforming them into Time Lords; they chose to limit a Time Lord's regenerations to twelve.

The Master reveals that the Doctor is the "timeless child".

Tecteun and the child were inducted into a clandestine organisation called the Division, the details of which were redacted from the Matrix.

Unless of Course the Master is lying

Answer (score 1):

1. You have two glasses. A[ ] B[ ]
2. You fill one up from the tap. A[=] B[ ]
3. You wait 5 minutes then travel back in time. pA[=] pB[ ] fA[=] fB[ ]
4. You pour your full cup into your past self's empty cup. pA[=] pB[=] fA[ ] fB[=]

Where did the extra water come from? Answer: there is no new water, it's the same old water.

The water started off in cup A in the past; it then got carried over to cup A in the future. That water was then poured from cup A in the future to cup B in the past. The water is then in cup B where it remains in the future.

At one point during all this, both cups are full; but for both cups to be full a cup in the future must be poured into a cup in the past.

Here's a diagram, with time passing from left to right:

[image: GlassWater]

Exchange the cups for timelords and the water for regeneration energy and you see that it's impossible to create infinite regeneration energy, the energy always has to go somewhere. The transfer is set in stone, any deviation would cause a paradox or some similar time problem.

If you prefer to think in terms of timelines, the energy/water's timeline is a linear piece of thread. All time travel does is fold the thread in on itself; the thread is still the same thread.

Comment: Exactly, once regeneration energy is gone, it's gone. It's like when people argue about the meta-crisis regeneration, it still counts as a change because he got rid of the energy of his potential 11th/12th incarnation. He can't get that back, ever... unless some weird reality warping thing were to happen. This is Doctor Who we're talking about, so who knows

Comment: @L.JRob Or if the timelords give him another set of regenerations. Which incidentally they have.

Comment: Exactly, this proves that the Doctor will die at some point, unless the Time Lords help him again

Comment: @L.JRob If you think the answer is good, please upvote.

Comment: Uh, how do I upvote?

Comment: @L.JRob The up arrow next to the number at the top left of the answer.

Comment: Ideally you should video yourself explaining this on a chalkboard.

Comment: Who do you think you are trying to apply logic to all the timey-wimey of Doctor Who?!??!!?

Answer (score 0):

My short answer is "Yes! Doctor Who is potentially immortal."

Feel free to prove this theory wrong after considering the following:

- The Doctor has met and even touched himself without any life threatening problems.
  See [Has The Doctor ever met himself?](http://drwho.answers.wikia.com/wiki/Has_The_Doctor_ever_met_himself)
- What is true in the Doctor's past is true in his future. In *The Day of the Doctor*, the War Doctor begins running some calculations on his sonic screwdriver which are completed on the eleventh Doctor's sonic screwdriver. This was apparently a rewrite of history in which the eleventh Doctor's screwdriver had not been running these calculations until that event.
- Time Lords can transfer regeneration energy to one another. Melody Pond uses an entire regeneration worth of energy, sacrificing her final regeneration, to save the Doctor's life in *[Let's Kill Hitler](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-YrV0G9e1fE)*. In *The Angels Take Manhattan*, the Doctor heals River Song's broken wrist with some portion of regeneration energy. In *The Time of the Doctor*, Time Lords transfer regeneration energy to the Doctor, allowing him to regenerate into his twelfth incarnation.

### The Doctor's Dupe Regeneration Hack

To avoid the paradox of him committing suicide in this process, let's say the Doctor has at least one regeneration left. He goes back in time just ten minutes in his own time line and transfers that regeneration energy to his past self. His past self now has two regenerations available. In theory, the future Doctor will now have two regenerations available as well.

If the future Doctor instantly receives a new regeneration upon transferring it to his past self in the same way that the future sonic screwdriver had been running calculations from the past, he could repeat this process until reaching his full capacity for regenerating energy. Then he could return to his time line, ten minutes in the future, and go about his business.

Comment: Bootstrap paradox, surely?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. At least to someone who actually watched the show.

Comment: Which part do you take issue with?

Comment: 1 - 1 + 1 = 1, not 2

Comment: That doesn't seem to be how it works in the Whoniverse. As in the sonic screwdriver example, his current state is determined by his past state. If his past self has two regenerations, so then will his current self until he uses one. It's not so linear with [Wibbly Wobbly Timey Wimey...Stuff](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vY_Ry8J_jdw)

Comment: @RyanLoremIpsum, you said it yourself: "...until he uses one". If he transfers it to someone, whether that be his past self or someone else, he (his present self) will no longer have it. As in, when he goes back to the present, he will have 1 regeneration, because he just gave one away. It doesn't matter that he gave it away in the past, because for him, the past is just what he was doing a minute ago; it has no relationship with the past as defined on any sort of absolute calendar.

Comment: So you're saying history won't be rewritten until his past self waits ten minutes and then opts not to go back in time. In which case, both will have the extra regeneration. Interesting.

Comment: As far as canon goes, the same principle that allowed for the sonic screwdriver calculation to work should apply to this scenario as well. I'm looking for an example from the show that contradicts this. I'm less interested in physics than the capabilities the character has been provided and demonstrated in the show.

Comment: How about the MANY times the Doctor has stated that he cannot cross his own timestream without dire consequences ("except for cheap tricks", of course). Going back and pouring regeneration energy into himself would be the most egregious tampering imaginable. I can't imagine the universe looking the other way on that one.

Comment: He has done this many times. The most outrageous example being The Day of the Doctor. They've blown that rule out of the water.

Comment: Up to The Day of the Doctor, there was much ambiguity about the 12 regeneration limit. It was mentioned once in the Old Who, and only alluded to on a couple of occasions in New Who (The Master claimed he was given a new set to fight in the Time War.)  However, after the events in TDotD, it is quite clear that a Time Lord cannot get more than 13 incarnations on his/her own.  So technically no, The Doctor is not immortal. However, the Time Lords can, and often do, grant themselves extensions. The exact methods and impact is yet unknown to us.

Comment: I agree. The biggest question yet to be addressed is the method of extending the regen cycle.

Comment: "This was apparently a rewrite of history in which the eleventh Doctor's screwdriver had not been running these calculations until that event" False. It had been doing so, but either went unnoticed or was just accepted.

Comment: @Pharap - if it's anything like my desktop computer, it's doing a lot behind the scenes without me ever knowing about it. Especially when I sleep at night.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, spoilers for *Doctor Who* season 12 below:

If *Doctor Who* episode "The Timeless Children" is to be believed, according to "The Master" The Doctor was not born on Gallifrey and was instead sent from a "Parallel Dimension" from Somewhere or Somewhen and was discovered by a native inhabitant of Gallifrey in "The Early Days Of Gallifrey" and experimented on to create the ability to Regenerate. But this could all be lies because it was told by The Master and someone who just happened to call themselves The Doctor rather conveniently whilst The Master controls aspects of the Matrix.

So yes if The Master is correct then He/She could infinitely give her/his past incarnations extra regeneration energy but it would be useless because if The Master is telling the truth then The Doctor is immortal.

Comment: We don’t actually know that The Doctor, when first discovered, had _infinite_ regenerations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible in theory.   But I can only recall a single instance of a future version of a timelord being wiped out from timeline changes.  So in practice it is not possible and has never happened.

Other answers have already established regeneration transfers particularly between River Song and the Doctor.   So I want to focus on the paradox issues.

The only example of a future Doctor being erased I'm aware of is the version of Matt Smith's Doctor that died on Trenzalore.  Changing that timeline involved a fairly large paradox of introducing Clara into the past of 11 so she could fall through the timescar left behind when he died.  Ultimately leading to a timeline change where the Peter Capaldi Doctor was created and 11 didn't die.  Note the Doctor commented that only Gallifrey could pull off a timeline change like that.

So if you could get anything from a future version of one's self and then keep the stuff and never give it back because that future no longer exists - yes mathematically that's a free lunch.  If somehow the version of 11 that had never met Clara and we never actually saw on screen had some spare lives and gave them away those regenerations would not disappear in my opinion.

But that kind of paradox does not generally exist in Doctor Who.  And the unseen version of 11 had none to give away anyway.

The Two Doctors special might be important to consider where 2 and 6 met for how time works in Doctor Who. Things that happened to 2, specifically some genetic changes, instantly started to affect 6.  But it didn't change any Doctor Who adventures that had occurred in between their lives or 6's past.  (This is kind of like how Back to the Future or Looper timeline updating works)

So if in a new adventure 6 gave lives to 2 I'm forced to conclude he normally would not disappear from the paradox but still exist to collect them back.  So no net gain ultimately.